# Java Account number Validation

Tags: java, arrays, calculation

Account Validation formula picture.

[image: Account Validation formula picture]

Hi ,

I am trying to validate the account number using the formula attached in the picture.

The account number would be in string. At end I need to check and return the correct account number after
perform the validation above correctly.

The account number would be different but for this example we can test with 21412900192413. 
I just have managed to separate both of the string to array with int datatype for each so that easier to perform
the calculation. Can anyone help me to complete this to validate the account according to the formula attached in the picture 
above please?

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("test");
    String strAccount = "21412900192413";
    String fixedValues = "65432987654320";
    //for account number
    String sampleString = strAccount;
      String[] stringArray = sampleString.split("");
      int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
         String numberAsString = stringArray[i];
         intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
      }
      System.out.println("Number of integers: " + intArray.length);
      System.out.println("The integers are:");
      for (int number1 : intArray) {
         System.out.println(number1);
      }

    //for fixed values
    String sampleFixedValues = fixedValues;
      String[] stringArray2 = sampleFixedValues.split("");
      int[] intArray2 = new int[stringArray2.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2.length; i++) {
         String numberAsString = stringArray2[i];
         intArray2[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
      }
      System.out.println("Number of fixed values: " + intArray2.length);
      System.out.println("The fixed values are:");
      for (int number2 : intArray2) {
         System.out.println(number2);
      }


}
```

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: You have demonstrated that you can use a `for` loop. Now you need another loop to iterate over both the account number digits and fixed value arrays. Then you need to implement the check digit formula. Can you attempt this and show your approach?

Comment: Your question should include what exactly it is that you ask, where your problem lies. Please take a moment to check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys , i got it at last. Please let me know if there are any easier way to achieve this. make it shorter if possible.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("test");
    boolean success = false;
    String strAccount = "21412900192413";
    String fixedValues = "65432987654320";
    //for account number
    String sampleString = strAccount;
      String[] stringArray = sampleString.split("");
      int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
         String numberAsString = stringArray[i];
         intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
      }
      System.out.println("Number of integers: " + intArray.length);
      System.out.println("The integers are:");
      for (int number1 : intArray) {
         System.out.println(number1);
      }

    //for fixed values
    String sampleFixedValues = fixedValues;
      String[] stringArray2 = sampleFixedValues.split("");
      int[] intArray2 = new int[stringArray2.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2.length; i++) {
         String numberAsString = stringArray2[i];
         intArray2[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
      }
      System.out.println("Number of fixed values: " + intArray2.length);
      System.out.println("The fixed values are:");
      for (int number2 : intArray2) {
         System.out.println(number2);
      }
      //for total
      int totalSum = 0;
      int[] total = new int[stringArray2.length];
      for (int j = 0; j < stringArray2.length; j++) {
          total[j] = intArray[j] * intArray2[j];
          System.out.println("Total: " + total[j]);
          totalSum = totalSum + total[j];
      }
      System.out.println("TotalSum: " + totalSum);

      //Check Digit Formula = 10 – (Total Modulus 11 / Total%11) 
      int digitFormula = 10 - (totalSum % 11);
      System.out.println("digitFormula: " + digitFormula);
      int lastNumber = intArray[intArray.length-1];
      System.out.println("lastNumber: " + lastNumber);
      if(digitFormula == lastNumber){
          success = true;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("test");
        String strAccount = "21412900192418";
        String fixedValues = "65432987654320";
        // for account number
        String[] stringArray = strAccount.split("");
        int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            String numberAsString = stringArray[i];
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of integers: " + intArray.length);
        System.out.println("The integers are:");
        for (int number1 : intArray) {
            System.out.println(number1);
        }

        // for fixed values
        String sampleFixedValues = fixedValues;
        String[] stringArray2 = sampleFixedValues.split("");
        int[] intArray2 = new int[stringArray2.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2.length; i++) {
            String numberAsString = stringArray2[i];
            intArray2[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of fixed values: " + intArray2.length);
        System.out.println("The fixed values are:");
        for (int number2 : intArray2) {
            System.out.println(number2);
        }

        int total = calculateTotal(intArray, intArray2);

        if (checkDigit(intArray, total)) {
            System.out.println("Valid Account Number...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalis Account Number...");
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkDigit(int[] original, int total) {
        int digit = 10 - (total % 11);

        if (original[original.length - 1] == digit)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    private static int calculateTotal(int[] original, int[] fixed) throws Exception {
        if (original.length != fixed.length) {
            throw new Exception("Account number length mismatch with Fixed Values.");
        }

        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
            int multi = original[i] * fixed[i];
            total += multi;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Here is what I tried on my end. Hope this helps.

Cheers !!!